# R lattice -- unexpected legend

Tags: r, lattice

I want to graphically compare carbon pools under different forms of land use.
I am reading in my data,
later I remove a factor level.

However, when I display the data the legend does not work.
The first legend symbol has no label, and
the deleted factor (SPEZIALKULTUREN) is still shown.

how can I control the legend?

A sample of the data is shown below
enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZIX2.png)

```
agdata <- read.csv("C:/Jandl/LfdProjekte/2017FAO/2020Paper/Agdata.csv", header =  FALSE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
colnames(agdata) <- c("State","AgType","Cpool")

agdata$Cpool <- as.numeric(agdata$Cpool)

levels(agdata$AgType)[levels(agdata$AgType)=="ACKERLAND"] <- "crop"
levels(agdata$AgType)[levels(agdata$AgType)=="ALMEN"] <- "alpine meadow"
levels(agdata$AgType)[levels(agdata$AgType)=="EXTENSIVES GRÜNLAND *"] <- "extens grassland"
levels(agdata$AgType)[levels(agdata$AgType)=="INTENSIVES GRÜNLAND**"] <- "intens grassland"
levels(agdata$AgType)[levels(agdata$AgType)=="WEINGARTEN***"] <- "vineyard"

#dropping SPEZIALKULTUREN
agdata <- subset(agdata,agdata$AgType !="SPEZIALKULTUREN")

agdata <- subset(agdata,agdata$State !="")
agdata <- subset(agdata,agdata$State !="Wien")


library(lattice)

colors = c("lightsalmon3", "lightgoldenrod2", "cadetblue4", "yellow", "red", "blue")

barchart(
data = agdata,
origin = 0,
Cpool ~ State,
groups = AgType ,
xlab = list (
label = "State",
font = 2,
cex = 1),
ylab= list (
label = "C pool t/ha",
font = 2,
cex = 1),
#ylim=c(0,25),
labels = TRUE,
auto.key = list(space="top", columns= 3),
par.settings = list(superpose.polygon = list(col = colors)))
```

Comment: Please don't share data as images because we can't copy/paste that into R so we can't run your code to see what your plot looks like. Share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) otherwise it will be very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it happened to me sometimes that, when using the *subset* function, removed factors remain empty in the dataframe and will occasionally show on some plots. For example, consider this simple dataset named "myexample":

```
> myexample 
  var1 var2
1    1    a
2    5    a
3    6    b
4    3    b
5    7    c
```

Now I can subset it to keep only rows where var2 is either a or b

```
> myexample2<-subset(myexample, var2=="a" | var2=="b")
> myexample2
  var1 var2
1    1    a
2    5    a
3    6    b
4    3    b
> levels(myexample2$var2)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

It will look like "c" was dropped, but it is still there. To properly get rid of it, you can use the function *droplevels()*

```
> myexample2<-droplevels(myexample2)
> myexample2
  var1 var2
1    1    a
2    5    a
3    6    b
4    3    b
> levels(myexample2$var2)
[1] "a" "b"
```

And now it is really gone. Maybe give it a try and see if at least the removed factor is no longer in the plot.